# WCF rename ArrayOf

Tags: wcf

I have created WCF using IOC container as below:

```
public class RegionWebService : IRegion
{
    private readonly IRegionService _regionService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public RegionWebService(IRegionService regionService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _regionService = regionService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public IEnumerable<WsRegionDto> GetRegions()
    {
        var regions = _regionService.GetAllAsync().Result;
        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<RegionDto>, IEnumerable<WsRegionDto>>(regions);
    }
}
```

WsRegionDto class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Region")]
public class WsRegionDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

WCF returns:

```
<ArrayOfRegion>
    <Region>
        <Name>ASPAC</Name>
    </Region>
    <Region>
        <Name>EMEA</Name>
    </Region>
    <Region>
        <Name>LATAM</Name>
    </Region>
    <Region>
        <Name>MEXICO</Name>
    </Region>
    <Region>
        <Name>N/A</Name>
    </Region>
    <Region>
        <Name>NAM</Name>
    </Region>
</ArrayOfRegion>
```

I have created WsRegionDto class for WCF purposes because I don't know what impact adding DataContract will have in case I would like use RegionDto in other places (different than WCF).
I would like to rename `ArrayOfRegion` with`Regions`.
How can I achieve that? I tried in google with no luck.

Comment: You can add the `[DataContract]` attribute to a class and it will behave normally if used in a non-WCF scenario - all the attribute does is tell WCF how to serialize the class with `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: @Tim To which class? My WsRegionDto already has this attribute.

Comment: You can have one `RegionDto` and mark it with `[DataContract]`.   For WCF, it will serialize the class using DataContractSerializer.  For any other uses, the attribute will be ignored.   This is in response to your saying " have created WsRegionDto class for WCF purposes because I don't know what impact adding DataContract will have in case I would like use RegionDto in other places (different than WCF)".

Comment: Thank you Tim for clarifications. Any ideas about ArrayOf?